# Postgres GROUP BY, SUBSTRING and SUM Query Issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, plv8

I am trying to write a GROUP BY query but I am struggling to achieve the desired result. I am including

1. A JSON object that represent the DB table with some data.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tb_transaction
>
> "tb_transaction": [
>
>
>     {
>         "id": "121",
>         "profile_id": "57",
>         "event_id": "45",
>         "activity_id": "67",
>         "payment_type": "EFT",
>         "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>         "gl_code": "1234-56-102-020",
>         "description": "Golf",
>         "amount": "1500",
>         "paid": "f",
>         "invoice_number": "0006"
>     },
>     {
>         "id": "117",
>         "profile_id": "57",
>         "event_id": "45",
>         "activity_id": "65",
>         "payment_type": "EFT",
>         "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>         "gl_code": "1234-56-102-056",
>         "description": "Cuppa",
>         "amount": "100",
>         "paid": "f",
>         "invoice_number": "0006"
>     },
>     {
>         "id": "120",
>         "profile_id": "57",
>         "event_id": "45",
>         "activity_id": "70",
>         "payment_type": "EFT",
>         "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>         "gl_code": "1234-13-102-064",
>         "description": "Nutrition & Lifestyle",
>         "amount": "510",
>         "paid": "f",
>         "invoice_number": "0006"
>     },
>     {
>         "id": "125",
>         "profile_id": "207",
>         "event_id": "45",
>         "activity_id": "65",
>         "payment_type": "Cash",
>         "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>         "gl_code": "1234-56-102-056",
>         "description": "Cuppa",
>         "amount": "100",
>         "paid": "f",
>         "invoice_number": "0007"
>     },
>     {
>         "id": "126",
>         "profile_id": "207",
>         "event_id": "45",
>         "activity_id": "65",
>         "payment_type": "Cash",
>         "transaction_type": "merchandise",
>         "gl_code": "3400-56-102-056",
>         "description": "Cap",
>         "amount": "20",
>         "paid": "f",
>         "invoice_number": "0007"
>     },
>     {
>         "id": "128",
>         "profile_id": "193",
>         "event_id": "45",
>         "activity_id": "70",
>         "payment_type": "SnapScan",
>         "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>         "gl_code": "1234-13-102-064",
>         "description": "Nutrition & Lifestyle",
>         "amount": "510",
>         "paid": "f",
>         "invoice_number": "0008"
>     },
>     {
>         "id": "131",
>         "profile_id": "193",
>         "event_id": "45",
>         "activity_id": "65",
>         "payment_type": "SnapScan",
>         "transaction_type": "merchandise",
>         "gl_code": "3400-56-102-056",
>         "description": "Water Bottle",
>         "amount": "10",
>         "paid": "f",
>         "invoice_number": "0008"
>     },
>     {
>         "id": "130",
>         "profile_id": "193",
>         "event_id": "45",
>         "activity_id": "65",
>         "payment_type": "SnapScan",
>         "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>         "gl_code": "1234-56-102-056",
>         "description": "Cuppa",
>         "amount": "100",
>         "paid": "f",
>         "invoice_number": "0008"
>     }
> ]
> ```

2. My current query and its result.

> ```
> SELECT gl_code, transaction_type, activity_id, payment_type, description, SUM(amount) AS amount
> FROM tb_transaction
> WHERE  event_id = 45 AND paid = false
> GROUP BY gl_code, transaction_type, activity_id, payment_type, description
> ORDER BY gl_code;
>
>
>
> "RECORDS": [
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-13-102-064",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "70",
>             "payment_type": "EFT",
>             "description": "Nutrition & Lifestyle",
>             "amount": "510"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-13-102-064",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "70",
>             "payment_type": "SnapScan",
>             "description": "Nutrition & Lifestyle",
>             "amount": "510"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-56-102-056",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "65",
>             "payment_type": "Cash",
>             "description": "Cuppa",
>             "amount": "100"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-56-102-056",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "65",
>             "payment_type": "EFT",
>             "description": "Cuppa",
>             "amount": "100"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-56-102-056",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "65",
>             "payment_type": "SnapScan",
>             "description": "Cuppa",
>             "amount": "100"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-56-102-020",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "67",
>             "payment_type": "EFT",
>             "description": "Golf",
>             "amount": "1500"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "3400-56-102-056",
>             "transaction_type": "merchandise",
>             "activity_id": "65",
>             "payment_type": "Cash",
>             "description": "Cap",
>             "amount": "20"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "3400-56-102-056",
>             "transaction_type": "merchandise",
>             "activity_id": "65",
>             "payment_type": "SnapScan",
>             "description": "Water Bottle",
>             "amount": "10"
>         }
>     ]
> ```

3. The desired result.

> ```
> `"RECORDS": [
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-13-102-064",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "70",
>             "payment_type": "EFT",
>             "description": "Nutrition & Lifestyle",
>             "amount": "510"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-13-102-064",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "70",
>             "payment_type": "SnapScan",
>             "description": "Nutrition & Lifestyle",
>             "amount": "510"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-56-102-056",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "65",
>             "payment_type": "Cash",
>             "description": "Cuppa",
>             "amount": "120"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-56-102-056",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "65",
>             "payment_type": "EFT",
>             "description": "Cuppa",
>             "amount": "100"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-56-102-056",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "65",
>             "payment_type": "SnapScan",
>             "description": "Cuppa",
>             "amount": "110"
>         },
>         {
>             "gl_code": "1234-56-102-020",
>             "transaction_type": "activity_registration",
>             "activity_id": "67",
>             "payment_type": "EFT",
>             "description": "Golf",
>             "amount": "1500"
>         }
>     ]'
> ```

The difference is very subtle. But you will see that I basically want to sum the records who's "payment_type" and last 3 digits of the "gl_code" are the same. For example "payment_type": "**Cash**" and "gl_code": "1234-56-102-**056**",

Any help will be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group by `payment_type` and last 3 digits of `gl_code` (and apparently some other columns), you can do

```
SELECT substring(gl_code, length(gl_code) - 3), 
  transaction_type, 
  activity_id, 
  payment_type, 
  description, 
  SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM tb_transaction
WHERE event_id = 45 AND paid = false
GROUP BY substring(gl_code, length(gl_code) - 3), 
  transaction_type, 
  activity_id, 
  payment_type, 
  description
ORDER BY gl_code;
```

Note however that this will only select the last 3 digits, and not an (arbitrary) `gl_code` from all those that share the same last 3 digits.

Comment: Thank you @dnswit. The result I get from you query looks great. The only other thing I would like is if it could sum the amount of the the records with the same payment_type and gl_code substring. Currently they are still separate.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you want to sum over all rows with identical gl_code substring and payment_type and not distinguish by activity_id, description, etc.? Then leave them our of the `select` and `group by` expression lists.

Comment: Flip now I see my mistake. Thank you for pointing it out to me and very quick responses @dnswit.